# How to keep the Text of a Read only TextBox after PostBack()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, postback, readonly

I have an ASP.NET `TextBox` and I want it to be `ReadOnly`. (The user modify it using another control)

But when there is a `PostBack()`, The text get reset to an empty string.

I understand that if you set the `ReadOnly` property to `True` of a `TextBox` it's content does not get saved through `PostBack()`.

Is there a way to keep the content after `PostBack()` and make the `TextBox` not editable by the user?

I tried to set the `Enabled` property to `False`,But still the content doesn't save after `PostBack()`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Another solution I found and easier one:

Add this to the Page Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

Comment: For anybody who has this issue inside a gridview, you can add this property during RowDataBound event

Comment: I have this issue inside a gridview. I added the above line in RowDataBound event. Everything is working fine. The textbox retains its value on postback. I was wondering if I could disable the textbox instead of making it readonly and still retain its value on postback.

Answer (score 6):

Have your other control store the value in a hidden field, and on postback, pull the value from the hidden field and push it into the textbox on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

`txtStartDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");`  on pageload in the best of the best solutions ,instead or Javascripts,hidden variables,cache,cookies,sessions & Caches.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value using `Request.Form[txtDate.UniqueID]`. You will get it !!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue but using Knockout binding 'enable' and ASP.Net Server Control Text.

This way:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="City" data-bind="value: city, enable: !hasZipCode()"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, when the form was submitted this field value was always empty. This occurred, I presume, because if the control is disabled, it is not persist on the ViewState chain.

I solved replacing bindig 'enable' by 'attr{ readonly: hasZipCode}'

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="City" data-bind="attr{ value: city, readonly: hasZipCode }">/asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with javascript in the onfocus event of the Textbox itself.

Doing it like this with javascript has the advantage that you don't need to do it in code behind, which can be difficult if you need to do it in gridviews or similar.

This javascript code is only tested on Internet Explorer and certain parts of it will only work on IE, like for example the createTextRange part which is there just to make the caret end up at the beginning of the text in the Textbox, but that part can be skipped if not needed.

If the core of this technique works on other browsers then it should be possible to make the code cross browser. The core of the idea here is the blur after setting readonly and then a timeout to set the focus again.

If you only set readonly then it does not become readonly until next time you give the Textbox focus.

And of course, the code can be put into a function instead which is called with "this" as argument.

```
  <asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtSomething" 
    runat="server"
    Text='<%# Bind("someData") %>'
    onfocus="
var rng = this.createTextRange();
rng.collapse();
rng.select();
if (this.allowFocusevent=='0') {return;};
this.allowFocusevent='0';
this.readOnly=true;
this.blur();
var that=this;
setTimeout(function(){that.focus()},0);
"
  />
```

Comment: Sorry that this approach will have a disadvantage - until you go into the textbox you don't know whether it's editable or not, which is not a good user experiance!

Comment: @Kris, that is easy to fix with style, which is why I did not discuss it here.

Answer (score -1):

Set the ContentEditable property of textbox to false ContentEditable="false"..
It wont allow you to edit the contents of the textbox
 ie;will make the textbox readonly and 
also will make the value stay in the textbox after postback..
I think its the easiest way to do it..

Comment: ContentEditable is an HTML property not an asp.net property. And it has no effect on inputs/textareas.